# Reload React Native App from Function Call Within App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage, react-props

I am using AsyncStorage to store University info in a React Native app. I am using Stack and Tab Navigators with Screens for my pages. All page content successfully re-renders the way I want once someone selects a different University. The header does not. I have no way to tell it that an AsyncStorage variable has been updated and to update state and re-render itself.

I would like to simply refresh the entire app once someone selects a new University. Then the variable, states, and props will all be up to date, i.e. the same thing as bringing up the Dev menu and reloading the app. I want a button in the app that calls a function and does this internally.

EDIT: Here is a snippet of the code from my Settings page. I need the "name" field of my AsyncStorage variable to change in my header of my Index file when the Submit button is pressed.

```
saveMSU() {
const object = {
  name: 'MONTANA STATE UNIVERSITY',
  site: 'http://msubobcats.com/index.aspx',
};
AsyncStorage.setItem('schoolObj', JSON.stringify(object));
  }
  saveUM() {
const object = {
  name: 'UNIVERSITY OF MONTANA',
  site: 'http://gogriz.com/',
};
AsyncStorage.setItem('schoolObj', JSON.stringify(object));
  }
  updateSchool = async () => {
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Tabs' })]
}));
  }
 render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>CHOOSE YOUR UNIVERSITY</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.saveMSU}>
      <Text>Montana State University</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.saveUM}>
      <Text>University of Montana</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Button onPress={this.updateSchool}>
      SUBMIT
    </Button>
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

This is the main part of my Index file. What I need to update when "Submit" is pressed in Setting is this.state.school.site and this.state.school.name. I like the idea of using deviceEventEmitter, but am a little stumped on how to actually implement it.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { school: Object, loaded: false };
  componentWillMount() {
this.retrieveItem('schoolObj').then((current) => {
  this.setState({ school: current, loaded: true });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Unable to retrieve data: ' + error);
});
  }
  async retrieveItem(key) {
try {
  const schoolItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
  const item = JSON.parse(schoolItem);
  return item;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
return;
  }
  render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Image style={styles.logoStyle} source={require('./media/UAT.png')} />
    { this.state.loaded &&
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(this.state.school.site)}>
        <Text style={styles.headingStyle}>
            {Object.values(this.state.school.name)}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }
    <Root screenProps={this.state.school} />
  </View>
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: What about this?? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncStorage` is really a bad idea its create issue once your code get more bigger but you can handle this by use setTimeout to AsyncStorage.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('title', JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.title));
                                _this.setState({getTitle: true});
                            }, 3000)
```

The above example I show how you use timeout to asyncStore if you want to update the value at same page only.

If you want to update AsyncStorage vale to other components (pages) you can use broadcast method:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('changeTitle', responseJson, null);
```

Put the above line of code at where you want to update your AsyncStorage. Now to get this on other page or let say anywhere in project simply put below code in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.emitter = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('changeToolBarTitle', this.changeToolBarTitle, null);
    }
```

Don't forgot to import DeviceEventEmitter in both this files

```
import {
    DeviceEventEmitter
} from 'react-native';
```

I hope you get your solution.

Comment: There seems to be a very limited amount of documentation on DeviceEventEmitter, but it seems like a quick solution. So if I have a listener in ComponentDidMount in say my index file (where my header text is determined), where would I do a state change based on when that listener is executed? And the .emit would be called in my Settings screen, where the AsyncStorage value is updated. I have a line in Settings when a function is called that updates the variable: AsyncStorage.setItem('schoolObj', JSON.stringify(object)); I then need to emit this back to the Index and update the title on the fly.

Comment: Your asyncStorage has a updated Value now right ? so you need to use that asyncStorage value where you needed.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit unclear why you want to reload the whole app just to access the appropriate data from a different screen. It might be useful to post a simplified version of you code so that your intention is a bit clear.

I'm assuming this is because you don't have a state container to manage your applicaiton state?

So, here are few things to try

- [Redux](https://redux.js.org)

Redux will manage application state. So that you can basically "setState" from any screen and access that state from any screen (simplification, but basically thats what it does)

- new [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) api

Basically same thing as Redux but without a lot of boilerplate. This would be a good starting point before jumping into Redux. Have a look at [Using React Context API video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISgz8F9z0aM) for how to use it

Lastly, you don't (shouldn't) need to "refresh the entire app once someone selects a new University". This would be an overkill and a highly unoptimised (not to mention unnecessary) way to do things. Furthermore, as your app becomes even a bit bigger (non trivial) this approach would not scale at all.

Start with [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (less learning curve) first and if you want to go further, try [Redux](https://redux.js.org) (steep learning curve) second

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right about the fact that a complete refresh would be overkill and unoptimized. It just seems like the easiest workaround solution if there was one quick line of code that would perform a refresh. It seems Redux is the widely accepted solution; I just need to take the time to learn it.

As for Context, I hadn't heard of that and it does seem like a useful tool. Tying it to changes on an AsyncStorage variable seems somewhat difficult but that also might be the way to go.

Thank you for the feedback; it's very helpful.